# Android NDK without experimental gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some confusion in the structure of the NDK built for the android studio 2.2.3 because now NDK not working with experimental gradle and cmake introduce which is new for me.

I have prebuilt shared library and I want to use into my project so, is it required to add Android.mk file and Application.mk file? If it is required then how do I link it with gradle? Please any one remove my confusion for the NDK.

Comment: step by step intro for CMake http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/migrate-to-stable

Answer (score 0):

If you work with prebuilt libraries, you don't need experimental plugin and you don't need to worry about CMake. The *'normal'* Android plugin looks for the prebuilt libraries in `src/main/jniLibs`, but you can override this in the **build.gradle** file:

```
android { sourceSets { main { 
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] 
}}}
```

Comment: if you have any example then please share with me becuse JNI working with pakage name so i thing only share library is not enough for the linking also required the native function declarations java class file required.

Comment: If your prebuilt SO has JNI methods, you simply need a Java class that defines `native` methods that have exactly same signature. If you don't, you must build your proxy SOm, too.